# Getting errors while installing gitlab hook plugin in jenkins on windows (64 bit)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

[image: [Error screenshot]

While installing the Gitlab hook plugin ,it is showing me an error.error screenshot for the same.

When Started Gitlab hook plugin ruby run time automatically start downloading and it will fail giving error as

> C:\Program Files\Jenkins\plugins\ruby-runtime\WEB-INF\lib\classes.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>     Following are the enviornment details
>
> 1.OS:Windows 7 (64 bit)
>    2.Jenkin version:1.639

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Jenkins 1.639 and a [fix will be available in 1.640](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31019). I recommend until then downgrading to 1.630. It works.